# No route found for "GET /bundles/framework/images/input_bg.gif"

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I have built a login form which works perfectly under development environment. But once I switch to production, the 500 error occurs. I checked prod.log the error is

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /bundles/framework/images/input_bg.gif"" at /Users/zhongxingguo/Sites/QuidzOMS/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 1883 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /bundles/framework/images/input_bg.gif\" .....
```

I tried to remove prod cache, it doesn't help. And I also checked the /web/bundles/framework/images folder, there is no input_bg.gif.

Can anyone help me out there?

Thanks a lot.

---

```
[2013-07-10 16:36:02] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'pj6krphgnjhj00js435pbr70d5' for key 'PRIMARY'" at /Users/zhongxingguo/Sites/QuidzOMS/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php line 154 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException: PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'pj6krphgnjhj00js435pbr70d5' for key 'PRIMARY' at /Users/zhongxingguo/Sites/QuidzOMS/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php:154, PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'pj6krphgnjhj00js435pbr70d5' for key 'PRIMARY' at /Users/zhongxingguo/Sites/QuidzOMS/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/PdoSessionHandler.php:239)"} []
[2013-07-10 16:36:02] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

---

Now I think the problem is caused by the pdoSessionHandler.
I store the session data in database, but sometimes when user logs out, the session data seems like is not cleared.

The error is like below:

```
PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'jq09f6s8eqvhvpiik322h0kkh1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Does anyone knows how to resolve the session problem?

My session configuration is:

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:   session.handler.pdo
services:
    pdo:
        class:  pdo
        arguments:
            - "mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%"
            - "%database_user%"
            - "%database_password%"
        calls:
            - [setAttribute, [3, 2]]

    session.handler.pdo:
        class:      Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        arguments:  ["@pdo", "%pdo.db_options%"]
```

Thank everyone helps me here.

Comment: check your htaccess file ensure your not routing request to images to your symphony controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I think the problem is not the .htaccess file. I just rewarmed the cache. Now the issue is, I can log in but 9 out 10 times it just response a 500 error. Sometimes by luck I can log in successfully. The error I have edtied in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an error in a path like `/bundles/something/whatever` I encourage you to make sure that your assets are correct.

Type this command:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

Is also recommended to clear cache with `--no-warmup` parameter, in my opinion.

If after that still not working, let's try something else.

I hope I helped you, mate ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dani. I have just found the reason might be Symfony generates duplicate key of the session. I'm not sure how this happened. I store the session in database, but it seems like sometimes when user logs out, the session is not cleaned. The error is like this: `PDOException was thrown when trying to read the session data: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'jq09f6s8eqvhvpiik322h0kkh1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: Forgive my question but, why are you storing the session in database? I'm asking because Symfony2 has a well handled native session management and storage. In the other hand, if you want to store it the database, you'll need to check if a session already exists before creating another one with the same primary value :)

Comment: Thanks Dani. I have checked through the code of PdoSessionHandler already but found nothing wrong with it. I have got no idea. As you said, I might change to native session for our project. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, mate :) I hope I've helped you. I know I haven't given you the answer you were looking for, but if you want to "thumbs up" my answer... feel free :D

Comment: Yes I am happy to share your answer which may help the others. :)

Comment: For the record, I'm experiencing this exact same bug in Symfony, both in dev and in prod. And it has nothing to do with assets.

Comment: Can you provide us more information? BTW, did you downvote me? I'm asking because, maybe, it's non-sense to downvote an approved solution for another user only because it didn't work for you and before you identify the origin of your problem :/

Comment: I did downvote you. Nothing personal obviously; I don't see how your answer addresses the question being asked. The question refers to an integrity constraint violation, which is a problem at the database layer, and is in no way related to the installation of assets, or the caching that Symfony employs. Having your answer marked as correct gives the impression that the problem was solved, which it clearly wasn't. Regardless, I've subsequently discovered that the problem stated in the question is a known bug, which has actually just been patched :) https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8448

Comment: If you pay attention to the title and the original post (first 5-6 lines) you could see that it was (firstly) oriented to a missing asset. Later, I agree with you, the question turned to another matter that was solved by the author himself. Finally, I'm glad you solved your own problem.